# Cryptographically random integer derived from crypto.getRandomValues()

Tags: javascript

I have come up with a function to generate a "cryptographically random" integer within a specific range (minDigits, maxDigits). It keeps generating until one fits the range defined. I would just like to know from someone who may have more knowledge if this is indeed viable.

In the example below I used range of minimum 6 and maximum 6 for a hopefully truly random 6 digit integer leveraging the Javascript Web Crypto API [crypto.getRandomValues()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) method.

More specifically, is this substantially more random than just using [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)?

```js
function secureRandomByDigits(minDigits, maxDigits) {
  if (minDigits <= 0 || maxDigits <= 0 || minDigits > maxDigits) {
    throw new Error('Invalid digit range');
  }

  const min = Math.pow(10, minDigits - 1);
  const max = Math.pow(10, maxDigits) - 1;

  // Generate a cryptographically secure random number until it fits the range
  let randomInt;
  do {
    const buffer = new Uint32Array(1);
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(buffer);
    const fraction = buffer[0] / 0xFFFFFFFF;
    randomInt = Math.floor(fraction * (max - min + 1) + min);
  } while (randomInt < min || randomInt > max);

  return randomInt;
}

// Example usage:
const randomInt = secureRandomByDigits(6, 6);
console.log("Random Integer:", randomInt);
```

Comment: What are you trying to determine?

Comment: If it is substantially more random than just using `Math.random()`.

Comment: Depends on the user agent. As the linked MDN page in your question states: "There is no minimum degree of entropy mandated by the Web Cryptography specification."

Comment: Yet they call it "...cryptographically strong random values". Love it.

Comment: Probably. You could also use `URL.createObjectURL(new Blob())` then match characters, integers, or combinations thereof, with optional `-` character. Keep in mind there really is no such thing as any "secure" signal communications.

Comment: I think these comments satisfy. Feel free to create an answer for me to accept or tell me to delete it if this doesn't really feel like a question. Thank you!

Comment: I think it's a valid question. Maybe someone will come along with relevant citations from the Web Crypto spec, or even information about the current implementations for common user agents.